# Delete MOST records from survey (not all)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, survey, survey-list

I need to delete records in a survey before they reach the big 5K threshold.  The problem is, I need to delete MOST of the records, but not ALL of them.  Since it's a survey, I can't seem to open it in a datasheet view as I can in a regular list. I'd also rather not go through each record and delete one by one (which would take forever).   Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "**Content and Structure**" feature to delete multiple surveys. Please remember to uncheck the surveys that you don't want to delete.
[Delete all data from an existing survey](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/delete-all-data-from-an-existing-survey-800de61b-f1b8-4185-a4df-4efa00cc4637)

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a view for the survey that will show all the items you want deleted.  Then run a script that will delete all items in a list view.  Check out this script for it [SP.List.recycleItems.js](https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/35a54ae726a2615548b0cfbb3c9ceeb3)

```
;(function(){
    var recycleItems = function(listViewName){
        listViewName = listViewName || false;
        var successMessage = 'Item(s) Recycled',
            ctx = this.get_context(),
            list = this,
            items,
            views = this.get_views(),
            view,
            counter,
            noop = function(){},
            error = function(sender, args){
                var message = args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_errorCode();
                console.error(message);
            },
            execute = function(payload,callback){
                payload = payload || null;
                callback = callback || noop;
                if(typeof(payload) === 'function'){
                    callback = payload;
                }
                if(payload !== null && callback !== payload){
                    ctx.load(payload);
                }
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(callback.bind(null,payload),error);
            },
            getView = function(){
                view = views.getByTitle(listViewName);
                execute(view,getItems);
            },
            getItems = function(){
                var camlQuery;
                if(!listViewName){
                    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
                }
                else{
                    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.set_viewXml(view.get_listViewXml());
                }
                items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
                execute(items,recycleItems);
            },
            success = function(sender, args){
                console.log(counter + ' ' + successMessage);
            },
            recycleItems = function(){
                var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                var recycleitems = [];
                while(enumerator.moveNext()){
                    var item = enumerator.get_current();
                    recycleitems.push(item);
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < recycleitems.length; i++){
                    recycleitems[i].recycle();
                    counter = i+1;
                }
                execute(success);
            };
        if(!listViewName){
            console.error('Error: You must provide a View Name');
        }
        else{
            getView();
        }
    }
    if(_v_dictSod['sp.js'].state === Sods.loaded){
        window.SP.List.prototype.recycleItems = recycleItems;
    }
    else{
        RegisterSod("sp.res.resx", "/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx");
        RegisterSod("sp.js", "/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js");
        RegisterSodDep("sp.js", "sp.res.resx");
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js',false,function(){
            window.SP.List.prototype.recycleItems = recycleItems;
        });
    }
}())
```

USAGE:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('<List Title>');
ctx.load(list);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function(){
    list.recycleItems('<Name of List View');
  },
  function(sender,args){
    console.error(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_errorCode();
  }
);
```

The above code sends items to the recycle bin where they would need to be deleted to restore space on the site collection.  You can use [SP.List.deleteItems.js](https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/1b2e7f989eb6ac58f365f4a7b3f6a8e1) to skip the recycle bin and delete completely in one swift keystroke.